# How to display an image in an JFrame?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am a beginner and am trying to program a small game. Unfortunately, I am currently failing to insert an image file on the JFrame.

I got this version from the internet, but unfortunately nothing is displayed when I run it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JLabel {

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D Graphic1 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Graphic1.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g.setColor(new Color(0, 191, 255)); // farbe hintergrund einstellen
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Var.Framebreite, Var.Framehöhe);

        g.setColor(Color.yellow);

        Font currentFont = g.getFont(); // schriftgröße von Leben bestimmen
        Font newFont = currentFont.deriveFont(currentFont.getSize() * 8F);
        g.setFont(newFont);

        double b = Math.round(0.125 * Var.Framebreite);
        int h = (int) b;

        g.drawString("" + Var.LebenSpieler1, Var.Framebreite / 2 - h - 100, 90); // Leben anzeige spieler
                                                                                    // !muss "" + variable geschriebeen
                                                                                    // werden

        g.drawString("" + Var.LebenSpieler2, Var.Framebreite / 2 + h, 90); // Lebven anzeigen gegnerspieler

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\justi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\OnlineSchule\\Englisch\\Test.PNG");
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel(icon);
        JPanel feld = new JPanel();
        feld.add(l1);
        feld.setBounds(30, 30, 110, 110);

        repaint();

    }
}
```

Comment: _What_ are you running? There's no main method in the code you posted.

Comment: I'd get rid of that example as it's not very good and is going a bunch of things which it shouldn't be doing

Comment: Your question is quite broad and requires a lot of "additional" context.  First thing you want to do is figure out how to load an image - [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html).  This becomes a little more complicated as you can load images from a number of different sources.

Comment: There are multiple ways of displaying a image in Swing, but if you want more control over how the image is displayed, then you should spend some time to better understand how painting works in Swing

Comment: *"got this version from the internet"* Put it back where you found it. Then pour petrol on it and light it on fire. It's horrible code & should not be used to misguide more people.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not create components in a painting method. A painting method is used to do painting with a Graphics object.
2. Do not invoke repaint() in  a painting method. This will cause a loop. If you need animation use a Swing Timer.
3. Do not do I/O in a painting method. The method will be called frequently and you want the painting to be efficient.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for examples of how to do painting. Download the working code and modify it for your requirments.

To paint an image you use the `drawImage(...)` method of the Graphics object.

You would read the image in your constructor and keep an instance variable to reference the image.